# Is it necessary to protect old devices against "new" 230V?

Tags: power-supply, motor, electric-machine

So, i was recently listening to old automatic music playing machines. These are devices from the year 1910 +/-. They are most likely purposed for 220V European power net.

To me, most of the machines sound like they are speeding trough their song and dance way too quickly.

An example is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3eBdKztfSHk 
This machine plays singing in the rain, and is the fastest rendition i heard to date.

So this made me wonder, does our current power net have something to do with this? Is it necessary to "downgrade" our power net for these kinds of machines to get their original experience, or would it be for a different reason?

In general, besides faster wear and tear that i can find documented on wiki's. What else affects old electrical devices on our modern power net?

Comment: A motor used for audio playback should not have its speed determined by the line voltage alone: it should either be a synchronous motor locked to the line frequency, or have some speed adjustment mechanism.  Are you using the designed line frequency?  Is the adjustor out of adjustment?  Also music tempo traditions seem to have varied with time, and there are (perhaps dubious) claims of fast tempos being used in the piano roll / early recordings era to try to fit full compositions on short media.

Comment: Are you running it on 60Hz while the machine is designed for 50Hz? It shouldn't be difficult to measure the duration of the music and compare with an reference to know how much faster it is.

Comment: I would think that after lovingly restoring such machines, the operators would take great care to ensure that the correct supply was used. So perhaps the machines were set to play quickly so as to be impressive, or they added more fiddly musical bits also to show off, which made it appear faster. The machine in the video you linked to played for as long as Gene Kelly sang and danced for. (I have no musical ability.)

Comment: @ChrisStratton That does make sense, the particular device apparently had multiple music plays (same device, different roll in it) which might be the reason for the unusual speed. They would simply "fill the roll" with whatever time it took. So they would either play it slow or fast if needed. I never even thought of that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your electric distribution network is almost the same when it was 220VAC. Once upon the time the UK had 240VAC and the the almost all european countries had 220VAC. Upon joining in EU they had just invented the new 230VAC standard, which only says that voltage tolerances are more loose, so the 220 and 240 standard becomes 230VAC with respective tolerance +/-.

Although, also if the voltage difference is real, the device won't suffer any damage or performance, so don't worry.

As for your playing machine: You should look the motor nameplate or at least make a photo of it. It can be DC motor or AC motor. If it's a kind of AC motor, then the speed is determined by the line frequency. If you connected it on 60Hz and it was built for 50Hz then you have this 20% faster tempo.

An autotransformer to match the supply voltage would be very small an cheap, but you would need a shop that will custom make it. If you want to vary the tempo, then an VFD inverter is needed for AC motor or power voltage regulator in case of DC motor.

Comment: Tell that to my xmas light bulbs. They all died at an impressive rate, until I decided to put a couple of diodes in series to kill half a sinusoid and lower a bit the voltage. Now they seem eternal.

Comment: Yes, it is a proven fact that 220V machines needed faster replacement, especially the really old radios and such, which still had tubes would get hotter than usual.

Answer (score 0):

From a safety point of view, it's highly unlikely you need to change anything unless the original product was dangerous to start with. As early as 1910 might have had a different/even wider tolerance but before the 230 V unified Europe, 220 and 240 V was +-10 % and "new" 230 V is +-6 % so you will still be within the tolerance band.

From a performance point of view, yes, it may be completely linear relation between speed and input voltage. Simplest but heaviest solution would be a transformer, either straight 230 V -> 220 V, an autotransformer/variac or if you find one multitapped primary with both 220 and 230 V with suitable VA rating, you are good to go.